# How to pass an array from one component to its sub component

Tags: arrays, angular, input, components, output

After googling lots of related answers and tries, I seemly have to seek help here.
I have an angular application, one of its components named stock-subscribe, which is used to display the feeTypes that a customer subscribed. Within this component, I created another component, stock-addsubs, used to display the feeTypes that are not yet subscribed by this customer.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25Dxy.jpg)

Obviously, the two feeType lists can compose one whole list. From stock-subscribe, I can get an array, subscribedFeeIds, which holds all the ids of those subscribed feeTypes.

My requirement is to pass this array, subscribedFeeIds, to the stock-addsubs component so that I can filter out those yet unsubscribed feeTypes based on those ids of the array.

To my best understanding, the data passing from one component to its sub component should be a simple process and neither of two component html templates should be involved for my case. Of the many googled solutions, using @Output and @Input seems the simpler than event emitting. However, none can successfully pass the elements of the array in the sub component.

I can get the expected id list (subscribedFeeIds[]) from the stock-subscribe component, and all the rest code work fine so long as the array passed to the sub component is not EMPTY.

**1) stock-subscribe.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-stock-subscribe',
      templateUrl: './stock-subscribe.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./stock-subscribe.component.scss']
    })
    export class StockSubscribeComponent implements OnInit {    
      userSubscribe: ISubscribe;    
      @Output() subscribedFeeIds: any = [];  

      listData: MatTableDataSource<any>;

      constructor(private accountService: AccountService,
                  private stockService: StockService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.createSubsList();    
      }

      createSubsList() {    
        this.accountService.getUserAccount()
          .subscribe(account => {      
          let userId = account.id.toString();            
          this.stockService.getUserSubscribes(userId).subscribe((data: ISubscribe[]) => {        
            
            // get the id of subscribed fee type and thenpublish to other component
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
            {
              if (data[i].status)
                this.subscribedFeeIds.push(data[i].fees[0].id);
            }
            console.log(this.subscribedFeeIds);

            // prepare the list source for display
            this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(data);
            this.listData.sort = this.sort; 
            }, error => {
              console.log(error);
          });
        }, error => {
          console.log(error);
        });    
      }
    }
```

**2) stock-addsubs.component.ts**

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-stock-addsubs',
      templateUrl: './stock-addsubs.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./stock-addsubs.component.scss']
    })
    export class StockAddsubsComponent implements OnInit {
      
      listData: MatTableDataSource<any>; 

      @Input() subscribedFeeIds: any []; 
      
      constructor(private feesService: FeesService) { }

      ngOnInit(): void {
        this.createFeeList();    
      }    

      createFeeList() {                
        this.feesService.getFeeList().subscribe((data: IFee[]) => { 
          
          // filter those already subscribed
          for (var i = 0; i < this.subscribedFeeIds.length; i++)
            {
              for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++)
              {
                data = data.filter(f => f.id != this.subscribedFeeIds[i]); 
              }          
            }

          // prepare data to display
          this.listData = new MatTableDataSource(data);      
          }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        });
      } 
}
```

Comment: Could you show the respective HTML code as well, where you're passing `subscribedFeeIds` to your child component? I didn't quite understand when you said `neither of two component html templates should be involved for my case`. You would have to do some property binding in your HTML to pass your array from the parent to child component.

Comment: These ids of the array to be passed won't be used in HTML, but only used as filter to get those not yet subscribed feeTypes. So these array's elements are only consumed in the ts. That's why I said "neither of two component html templates should be involved for my case". Sorry for confusing you, ignore it. And that's why I didn't post HTML here. Thanks for your time and whatever input here, thanks Sir.

Comment: But as @Tarun said you need a connection between the two components. So either import it or use it in the HTML and import it implicit.

Comment: Thanks to Tarun and Mainz. here is my HTMLs.

Comment: Thanks to Tarun and Mainz. here is my HTMLs. You may notice that there is no property of columnToDisplay in the previously posted ts, being removed for a clean purpose.

Comment: 3) stock-subscribe.component.html
<div class="container"> 
    <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Subscribe # </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
        </ng-container>        
        ....        
    </mat-table>
</div>

Comment: 4) stock-addsubs.component.html
<div class="container">
    <mat-table [dataSource]="listData" matSort>
        <ng-container matColumnDef="id">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> Service # </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.id}} </mat-cell>
            <mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef></mat-footer-cell>
        </ng-container>  
        ....
    </mat-table> 
</div>

Comment: Sorry, it seems impossible for me to post the entire html files due to the characters limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement either one of these methods:

**1.) Enhance your `@Input` and `@Output` based on your code above:**

*stock-subscribe.component.ts*

```
@Component({...})
export class StockSubscribeComponent implements OnInit {    

   @Output() subscribedFeeIds: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(); 

   list: any[] = [];               // To store your ids, do not use the @Output variable above to push things inside a loop, you may not want to continuously emit data for an nth number of the sequence.

   ...

   createSubsList() {    

      ...
    
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        ...
    
        if (data[i].status)
           this.list.push(data[i].fees[0].id);      // Push IDs on this.list not on this.subscribedFeeIds
      }  

      this.subscribedFeeIds.emit(this.list);        // After the loop finishes, emit the final list value
                                                    // Do not use .push() on @Output variable, this is an emission variable so use .emit()

   

   }

}
```

or you could also do any of these methods when handling your array list:

```
// METHOD #1
this.filteredIds = [];
for(const { status, fees } of FEES_DATA) {
   if (status) filteredIds.push(fees[0].id);
}

OR    

// METHOD #2
this.filteredIds = FEES_DATA
  .filter(({ status }) => status)
  .map(({ fees }) => fees[0].id);



// Then emit the filtered ids
this.list.emit(this.filteredIds);
```

*stock-addsubs.component.ts*

```
@Component({...})
export class StockAddsubsComponent implements OnInit {

   // Since you are waiting for emission from StockSubscribeComponent which the 
   // emission also waits till the loop is finished based on the code above, better to
   // implement the @Input like this so as to avoid processing a an empty list

   @Input() set subscribedFeeIds(list: any[]) {
       if (list && list.length) {              // If the list now has items, call createFeeList() function
         this.createFeeList();
       }
   } 

   ...

}

____

or

@Component({...})
export class StockAddsubsComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {    // Add OnChanges

  @Input() subscribedFeeIds: any []; 


  ngOnChanges({ subscribedFeeIds }: SimpleChanges) {          // SimpleChanges from @angular/core

    if (subscribedFeeIds && subscribedFeeIds.currentValue && subscribedFeeIds.currentValue.length) {
      this.createFeeList();
    }

    // You can also console the subscribedFeeIds and check it's value or changes
    console.log(subscribedFeeIds);

  }

}
```

Have created a **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-output-basic?file=src/app/child-2/child-2.component.html)** for your reference

---

**2.) Use RxJS `Subject` or `BehaviorSubject` to emit data**

Use this **[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-behavior-subject?file=src/app/app.component.ts)** for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for taking time answering my question. Can please take another look at the Solution 1 as I get empty list in the subcomponent?  On the basis of your 1st solution, I just simply change the original 
@Output() subscribedFeeIds: any = [];  to 
@Output() subscribedFeeIds = new EventEmitter();
in order to emit the list.

Comment: Sorry, have edited the @Output() into "@Output() subscribedFeeIds: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>(); " and yes, it's the same as of the method #1 which would be a possible solution for your problem. May I know if it fixes on your side or if i have missed something?

Comment: with the new @Output emit variable, the error remains like:
EventEmitter {_isScalar: false, observers: Array(0), closed: false, isStopped: false, hasError: false, …}
closed: false
hasError: false
isStopped: false
observers: Array(0)
length: 0

Comment: did you use "this.subscribedFeeIds.emit(<YOUR_DATA>)" where you use ".emit" function not assigning it with "=", yours was "this.subscribedFeeIds.push(data[i].fees[0].id);". See the above example but i can provide a sample demo if it still confuses you?

Comment: yes, should have followed your solution: push to the list, then emit it after the loop finished.
1) this.list.push(data[i].fees[0].id);
2)  this.subscribedFeeIds.emit(this.list);

Comment: Have created a Stackblitz Demo for your reference, May I know if this helps you with the problem :) Have also updated the answer above.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-output-basic?file=src/app/child-2/child-2.component.html

Comment: This is a great demo! Thanks for the efforts you have made. I can recreate the exactly same one test demo within my project, works perfectly! However, the same logic applied to my real components always failed - emitting empty array. As the ids[ ] was coming from the observables via http API request, very likely the emitter launched before ids reach the array. Wired enough, the console does log the ids[] every time. if this assumption makes sense, is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: If it's that the case, you can refer to the code sample above under `stock-addsubs.component.ts` where we have this code @Input() set subscribedFeeIds(list: any[]) { .... }, adding set inside the @Input() so you can check if the list exists and it contains data, you can call your respective next function by then to call and process your list IDs. If that helps?

Comment: I think I eventually get it work as advised. Thanks for all...